# SQL run part of the script only in a specific case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql for calculate sums:

```
SELECT l.name, CASE WHEN l.child_leads_ids <> '' THEN SUM(kosten_einkauf) + (SELECT SUM(cl.kosten_einkauf) FROM leads as cl WHERE cl.lead_id IN (l.child_leads_ids)) ELSE SUM(l.kosten_einkauf) END AS sumValue FROM leads as l WHERE (l.name LIKE '%Test%' || l.first_name LIKE '%Test%' || l.nick_name LIKE '%Test%' || l.name_vorname_partner LIKE '%Test%') AND l.is_active = 1 AND l.is_archive = 0 AND dont_show_in_list=0 and l.is_parent_lead <> 2 GROUP BY l.name
```

How can i add rules that run select inside case only for `cl.is_active = 1 AND cl.is_archive = 0 AND cl.dont_show_in_list=0`

A repeat of the query, formatted.

```
SELECT l.name, 
       CASE WHEN l.child_leads_ids <> '' 
            THEN SUM(kosten_einkauf) + (
                    SELECT SUM(cl.kosten_einkauf)
                      FROM leads as cl
                     WHERE cl.lead_id IN (l.child_leads_ids))
            ELSE SUM(l.kosten_einkauf) END AS sumValue 
  FROM leads as l 
  WHERE (l.name LIKE '%Test%' || 
         l.first_name LIKE '%Test%' || 
         l.nick_name LIKE '%Test%' ||
         l.name_vorname_partner LIKE '%Test%')
    AND l.is_active = 1 AND l.is_archive = 0
    AND dont_show_in_list=0
    and l.is_parent_lead <> 2
  GROUP BY l.name
```

Comment: Why don't you put these rules in the WHERE clause of the select statement?

Comment: ... and what happens to the other rows that do not match that criteria?

Comment: And also, don't use the word "script" since it produces confusion. SQL statements are **declarative** and not an **imperative** script that runs sequentially or something.

Comment: to add to @TheImpaler 's comment because SQL is declarative and compiles on runtime we also don't know for sure the result of your query without knowing table structure, example data and expected results.. We can only make educated guesses.. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Comment: You can just replace WHERE cl.lead_id IN (l.child_leads_ids) with WHERE cl.lead_id IN (l.child_leads_ids) and cl.is_active = 1 AND cl.is_archive = 0 AND cl.dont_show_in_list=0